# Combine conditions with AND in Mysql ON clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following query, that I use to filter rows based on software_id and level. 
I've put the conditions in the ON-Clause since I still want rows returned, where there are no corresponding rows in the JobadvertsSoftware Table.

```
SELECT `Jobadvert`.`id` FROM `jobadverts` AS `Jobadvert` 

LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` ON (`Jobadvert`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 

LEFT JOIN `jobadverts_softwares` AS `JobadvertsSoftware_0` ON
(`Jobadvert`.`id` = 'JobadvertsSoftware_0.jobadvert_id' AND 
(`JobadvertsSoftware_0`.`software_id` = '32' AND 
`JobadvertsSoftware_0`.`level` IN ('1', 4))) 


WHERE `Jobadvert`.`active` = 1 AND `User`.`premium` = '1' AND 
Jobadvert`.`department_id` = (5) 

GROUP BY `Jobadvert`.`id`
```

The problem is that it also returns JobadvertsSoftware-rows where level is e.g. 2
Again, if I put that in the WHERE clause it will filter out the rows where there are not JobadvertsSoftware which it shouldn't do.
How can I tell MySQL to return all rows of Jobadvert, where the given software_id AND the level matches or are NULL?

Comment: If you used an INNER JOIN instead of an OUTER JOIN, would that give you what you wanted?

Comment: suggest using shorter alias

Comment: put "level" that in your WHERE clause

Comment: This look suspicious because of the mixed data type: "`JobadvertsSoftware_0`.`level` IN ('1', 4)". Is level an integer or a string.

Comment: Any luck with the solutions? Just to clarify, which join fields need to joined between sortware and adverts and which null value fields do you need to include?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT `Jobadvert`.`id`, `JobadvertsSoftware_0`.`level` 
FROM `jobadverts` AS `Jobadvert` 

LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` ON (`Jobadvert`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 

INNER JOIN `jobadverts_softwares` AS `JobadvertsSoftware_0` ON
(`Jobadvert`.`id` = 'JobadvertsSoftware_0.jobadvert_id' AND 
(`JobadvertsSoftware_0`.`software_id` = '32' AND 
`JobadvertsSoftware_0`.`level` IN ('1', 4))) 


WHERE `Jobadvert`.`active` = 1 AND `User`.`premium` = '1' AND 
Jobadvert`.`department_id` = (5) 

GROUP BY `Jobadvert`.`id`
```

Saludos!

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. using an INNER JOIN will not return any rows at all

Answer (score 0):

Try this( it's a bit unclear if some fields are numeric on string, it might be corrected):

```
SELECT distinct(`Jobadvert`.`id`) FROM `jobadverts` AS `Jobadvert`  
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` ON (`Jobadvert`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `jobadverts_softwares` AS `JobadvertsSoftware_0` 
ON `Jobadvert`.`id` =     `JobadvertsSoftware_0.jobadvert_id`
WHERE 
`Jobadvert`.`active` = 1 
AND `User`.`premium` = '1' 
AND Jobadvert`.`department_id` = (5) 
AND JobadvertsSoftware_0`.`software_id` = '32' 
AND (`JobadvertsSoftware_0`.`level` IN (1, 4) OR `JobadvertsSoftware_0`.`level` is NULL)
```

Comment: Your syntax is broken halfway through on : ON `Jobadvert`.`id` =     `JobadvertsSoftware_0.jobadvert_id'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the level parameters in your ON clause is not needed for the join you can do a nested SELECT on your Software table to clear out the data you do not need first:

```
SELECT * FROM jobadverts_softwares
WHERE 
   (`software_id` = 32 OR `software_id` IS NULL) --Select all software_id that are 32 or null
AND
   `level` IN (1, 4)
```

Then you can incorporate this as a nested statement in your main SQL query so you only join on the data which is filtered in your LEFT JOIN but keep any null values that you needed:

```
SELECT `Jobadvert`.`id` 
FROM `jobadverts` AS `Jobadvert` 

LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User`
ON `Jobadvert`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`

LEFT JOIN 
(   --Software Subquery
    SELECT `jobadvert_id`, `level` FROM jobadverts_softwares
    WHERE 
       (`software_id` = 32 OR `software_id` IS NULL) --Select all software_id that are 32 or null
    AND
       `level` IN (1, 4)
) AS `software_subquery`

ON `Jobadvert`.`id` = `software_subquery`.`jobadvert_id`

WHERE
    `Jobadvert`.`active` = 1
AND 
    `User`.`premium` = '1'
AND 
    `Jobadvert`.`department_id` = 5 

ORDER BY `Jobadvert`.`id` --Changed GROUP BY to ORDER BY as not needed
```

This is untested but try it out and see if this will help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT j.id 
FROM jobadverts j 
LEFT JOIN User u ON (j.user_id = u.id) 
LEFT JOIN jobadverts_softwares AS js ON
(j.id = js.jobadvert_id)
WHERE j.active = 1 
  AND u.premium = '1' 
  AND j.department_id = (5) 
  AND js.software_id` = '32' 
  AND js.level IN ('1', 4)))
```

You won't need a GROUP BY unless summing data in some way.

Comment: make sure you surround the table name in angled quotes and correct it to `users` I like the shortened aliases though, much easier to read.